SymmetricDS can't seed, load table on replication DB
I'm trying to create a table on destination DB from source db using it's load function. As a documentation SymmetricDS_load it should seed the table on the destination DB but it's keep giving me this error
[master-engine] - DataService - Queueing up a load to node 002
[master-engine] - DataService - Cancelling load 7
[master-engine] - DataService - Table reload request submitted which does not have a valid trigger/router combination in sym_trigger_router. Request trigger id: 'pablo' router id: 'default' create time: 2024-11-25 03:48:35.72
[master-engine] - PushService - Push data sent to destination:002:002

My sym_router is:



router_id
target_catalog_name
target_schema_name
target_table_name
source_node_group_id
target_node_group_id
router_type
router_expression
sync_on_update
sync_on_insert
sync_on_delete
use_source_catalog_schema
create_time
last_update_by
last_update_time
description




destination to source
NULL
NULL
NULL
destination
source
default
NULL
1
1
1
0
05:59.6
NULL
05:59.6
NULL


source to destination
NULL
NULL
simple_table
source
destination
default
NULL
1
1
1
0
05:59.6
NULL
05:59.6
NULL


default
NULL
NULL
NULL
source
destination
default
NULL
1
1
1
1
43:01.3
NULL
43:01.3
NULL



Sym_router_trigger:



trigger_id
router_id
enabled
initial_load_order
initial_load_select
initial_load_delete_stmt
ping_back_enabled
create_time
last_update_by
last_update_time
description
data_refresh_type




pablo
source to destination
1
1
NULL
NULL
0
47:08.0
NULL
47:08.0
NULL
NULL



Sym_trigger:



trigger_id
source_catalog_name
source_schema_name
source_table_name
channel_id
reload_channel_id
sync_on_update
sync_on_insert
sync_on_delete
sync_on_incoming_batch
name_for_update_trigger
name_for_insert_trigger
name_for_delete_trigger
sync_on_update_condition
sync_on_insert_condition
sync_on_delete_condition
custom_before_update_text
custom_before_insert_text
custom_before_delete_text
custom_on_update_text
custom_on_insert_text
custom_on_delete_text
external_select
tx_id_expression
channel_expression
excluded_column_names
included_column_names
sync_key_names
use_stream_lobs
use_capture_lobs
use_capture_old_data
use_handle_key_updates
stream_row
time_based_column_name
create_time
last_update_by
last_update_time
description




pablo
NULL
public
sample_table
default
reload
1
1
1
1
NULL
NULL
NULL
1=1
1=1
1=1
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0
0
1
1
0
NULL
12:41.0
NULL
12:41.0
NULL





It's not working until I create the table on destination by manually. BTW it's Postgres to Oracle.

I just found that the cause of the error is I misconfigured the router_id. It was default -> source to destination
and I have now error that
Error Message = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. It should create the table on the destination right?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You will need to request the tables are created as part of the load request.
This is done by setting the following parameter to true:
initial.load.create.first=true

If this parameter is set in the engine file, then a restart will be required. If it is set in the database, no restart will be required.
This will send the creation of each table to the target before sending the data.
